# How does flush() output received messages/

Tags: erlang

`flush()` outputs received messages. The Learn You Some Erlang [book](http://learnyousomeerlang.com/more-on-multiprocessing) shows the following code for `flush()`.

```
flush() ->
    receive
        _ -> flush()
    after 0 ->
        ok
    end.
```

But how can it possibly output something like when it doesn't seem to do anything with the messages it receives.

```
8> flush().
Shell got {<0.51.0>,ok}
Shell got {<0.51.0>,{ok,bacon}}
Shell got {<0.51.0>,not_found}
ok
```

Comment: In the tutorial you linked to the four lines after flush() are results of storing the bacon, taking the bacon, not finding the turkey, and getting to the end of the message que respectivly.... Can you elaborate further on your question? not sure what else your asking

Answer (score 2, accepted):

flush() is a VM command that has nothing to do with the flush() example which purpose is to illustrate one usage of `after 0` (Of course both code empty the message queue). I guess that the code of flush in the VM looks like:

```
flush() ->
    receive
        M -> 
            io:format("Shell got ~p~n",[M]),
            flush()
    after 0 ->
        ok
    end.
```